# Scroll Up in a scrollable Table a marked row to the top

Tags: jquery, scroll, html-table, automation

http://jsfiddle.net/3tpqnu1v/

I've a small table and marked a special row with the a class as "active".
how is it possible that this marked row is automatic scrolled to the top or bottom or center of this table:

```
<table id="table" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>h1</th>
            <th>h2</th>
            <th>h3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active">
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this but I couldn't get the offset position exactly right from the row. You need to play around with getting the right ypos.

http://jsfiddle.net/3tpqnu1v/2/

```
 $('#scroll').on('click',function(e){
    var ypos = $('#table tr.active').offset().top - $("#table").offset().top - $('#table tr.active').height() ;
    $('#table tbody').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#table tbody').scrollTop() + ypos
    }, 500);
 });
```